# Is there any way to have as much variables in struct in c++ as I want? C++

Tags: c++

For example, after starting the program, I specify the number 4, and there are only 4 variables in my struct - x1, x2, x3, x4. If I enter 2 the next time I start the program, I will only have x1, x2. Is that even possible?

Comment: I think what you are looking for is this : struct { std::vector<int> x; }, https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/an-introduction-to-stdvector/

Comment: Structs have certain number of fields with unique names. What you are looking for is an array. But you want your arrays size to be determined in runtime. So you need to 'dynamically allocate' your array. @PepijnKramer 's suggestion should work, but I recommend you learn about dynamic memory allocation as it is an important topic.

Comment: @HeyYO I disagree, dynamic memory managment in C++ is something that should be learned after people have learned how to use the standard library. Manual managment of new/delete is one of the biggest causes of bugs/memory leaks and causes a lot of pain for starting programmers, removing a lot of the joy of learning how to program. Even the C++ committe aknowledges this, have a look at this: https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines and check all guidelines regarding pointers and memory allocation.

Comment: @PepijnKramer array would be great, but sadly I have to use struct, nothing else.

Comment: You could have your program get the input from the user, then generate the source code using that value, compile that program, and `exec` that program to run it.

Comment: @Err041 that doesn't make sense, what is the exact wording of your excercise?

Comment: What are you going to do with the fire truck after you've caught it? Suppose you have a struct with 80 members. How do you intend to access them programmatically?

Comment: Variables are defined at compile-time, so the only way to change the number of variables in a struct is to modify the source code and then recompile the program.  If you need to stored a list of values whose size needs to be chosen at run-time, then `std::vector` (or some other similar data structure) is the mechanism to obtain that.

Answer (score 0):

You can select the number of members of a struct at compile time and with template specialization you can even name them `x1`,`x2`,...

```
template <unsigned N>
struct foo;

template <>
struct foo<2> {
    int x1;
    int x2;
};

template <>
struct foo<4> {
    int x1;
    int x2;
    int x3;
    int x4;
};
```

Now `foo<2>` has members `x1` and `x2` and `foo<4>` has members `x1`,`x2`,`x3` and `x4`. However, you can only choose between `foo<2>` and `foo<4>` at compile time. Moreover the above is a little silly. Nobody would actually write code like that.

At runtime you would have to resort to runtime polymorphism, but I also doubt that that is what the exercise is asking you to do.

Whenever you feel like naming variables `x1`,`x2`,`x3`, ... then you actually want an array or vector:

```
 struct bar {
      std::vector<int> data;
      bar(unsigned size) : data{size} {}
 };
```

Now `bar b2{2};` holds 2 elements while `bar b4{4};` holds 4 elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have this in C++. The closest thing I can think of is using std::map. For example, here's a sample code to achieve this:

```
std::map<int, int> variables;
int numberOfVariables;
std::cin >> numberOfVariables;
for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfVariables; i++)
    variables[i] = SOME_VALUE;
```

With using maps, you can access your `i`th variable with `variables[i]`.

I recommend reading about maps (and other containers of C++) to get a better idea of what you can and can't do. [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com) is a good source for this.